# What Happens At An Equilibrium Point For An Autonomous First-Order Differential Equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $\frac{dx}{dt} =f(x)$ be an autonomous first-order differential equation with equilibrium point at $x_0$.

a) Suppose $f'(x_0) = 0$. What can you say about the behaviour of the solution near $x_0$. Give examples.

b) Suppose $f'(x_0) = 0$ and $f''(x_0)\neq 0$. What can you say now?

I attempted to do a. It looks like the behaviour at point $x_0$ could either be a sink/source at least from the examples I tried using. i.e. I used $f(x) = x^2, f(x) = x^3$ . Otherwise, I can't really think of a way to attempt this.

Any help?

Comment: Just to be sure, the space is $\mathbb{R}$ (or an open interval around $x_0$), right?